# Firebase listener not listening to signed in user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

> /FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( wmXtRaDooVcABlqA8UCRSLSE0qG2 ).
>   D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( wmXtRaDooVcABlqA8UCRSLSE0qG2 ).
>   D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
>   D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
>   D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
>   D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.

This is from the logs. So I signed in, but it is not working. Here is code for the **Login:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
EditText editText2;
Button button;
public FirebaseAuth Auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
public FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authlistener;
String email, pass;
ProgressBar bar;

public View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View view){
        email = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        pass = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
        logInUser();

    }};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    authlistener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in

            } else {
                // User is signed out

            }
            // ...
        }
    };
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Auth.addAuthStateListener(authlistener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (authlistener != null) {
        Auth.removeAuthStateListener(authlistener);
    }
}

public void logInUser(){
    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Intent loggedInActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Loggedin.class);
                        startActivity(loggedInActivity);

                    }
                    else{

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There was an error, try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }


                }
            });


}
}
```

**Code for loggedIn (the next intent, after login)**

```
public class Loggedin extends AppCompatActivity {

Button changeMail, changePass;
String oldPassword;
String newPassword;
EditText oldpass, newpass;
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
public FirebaseAuth Auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
public FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener AuthListener;

public void updatePassword(){
    oldPassword = oldpass.getText().toString();
    newPassword = newpass.getText().toString();



}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loggedin);
    changeMail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.changeMail);
    changePass = (Button)findViewById(R.id.changePass);
    oldpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.oldPass);
    newpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newPass);
    oldpass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    newpass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    AuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Log.i("hello", "hi" + user.getUid());

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    };


}
}
```

As you see, I have a listener set up in LoggedIn.Java, but it does not get the login data? Why is it like this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you are trying to change\update the existing password with new password.And this is happening only when the user has been logged in. So, here you don't need `AuthStateListener`.

Just use this function:

```
    void ChangePassword(){
            EditText newPassword = null;
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    
            user.updatePassword(newPassword.getText().toString().trim())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Password is updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Failed to update password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();                            
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
```

If successful proceed or handle the else part as required.

Answer (score 0):

Check once Firebase database reference is different in Registration or Login page this happens.